# SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 ONLY IN Safari

Tags: html, canvas, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

i got two servers (prod.example.com and img.example.com)

so on "prod" i process images from "img" using canvas

in FF and Chrome all is Ok

but in Safari i got this `SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.`

all images from "img" has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in headers

so where is padla?

Comment: Where is [padla](https://www.bing.com/maps?&q=Padla&ppois=29.8007907867432_76.2984008789062_Padla)?

Answer (score 2):

`getImageData` which you probably call will raise this if you try to access the one host from the other. You cannot go around this, the only way around it would be to proxy from img.example.com to prod.example.com

Comment: i thought that if "prod" and "img" is sub domains of example.com then `getImageData` is allowed

Comment: I don't think so. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/origin-0.html#same-origin , my understanding is that the hosts are different for subdomains. You could also try the document.domain at the end since you have control on both servers.

Comment: as i understand `document.domain` works only for cross-domain scripting and not on `getImageData`
so i`ll try to make a proxy, thanx

Comment: Btw, you can also proxy on your front-end (apache or nginx or whatever), if that makes it easier than proxying on your web server.

Comment: i really do not understand why `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not working