# load an image via ajax into canvas

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas, safari, cors

It relates to another question  [Cross Origin Resource Sharing Headers not working only for safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690686/cross-origin-resource-sharing-headers-not-working-only-for-safari) .

I am trying to load an image into canvas from s3.
Seems `safari < 6.0` has a bug related to loading images via CORS. So the canvas get tainted though the image has cors enabled. So I was thinking if there is some way to make an ajax request and then load the response into a canvas ?

Note : Ajax request works properly with CORS. Just that while loading image safari doesn't respect the `crossOrigin` attribute and hence the request is made without cross-origin.

- I have my images at s3 so there is no way to encode it to base64 and get it from amazon directly
- I am preferring not to set up a proxy at my domain for the image

some javascript

```
var img_location = "//temp_upload_test.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_0222.JPG"
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){

    console.log("image loaded")
    EXIF.getData(img,function(){
        console.log("image data read");
        var orientation = EXIF.getTag(img,'Orientation');
        console.log("orientation"+orientation);
        load_image_into_canvas_with_orientation(img,orientation);
    })
    console.log("image loaded function complete");
}
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
$(img).attr("crossOrigin","anonymous");
img.src = img_location;
```

One way I am trying to approach the problem is make an xhr request to s3. get the image as `BinaryFile` and then decode it to `base64` and use it as img's `src` . But while decoding I get a DOM exception not sure if the idea itself is wrong

Comment: Couldn't it help us help you if you provided your code? So we can at least exactly how you're handling it now

Comment: what part of code are you looking for ? the way I load the image from s3 ?

Comment: Yep, exactly, I'm just wondering how you already do it

Comment: I would think to do it like: `var base_image = new Image(); base_image.src = 'URL_TO_YOUR_S3_FILE'; base_image.onload = function () { var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100); };` but I really don't work with canvas

Comment: @lan after what you told try `canvas.toDataUrl()` and it will throw DOM exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299120/security-err-dom-exception-18-only-in-safari

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21502/discussion-between-gaurav-shah-and-ian)

Comment: Hmm interesting. Had no idea there would be cross-domain problems with this but I guess that makes sense. No idea why Safari wouldn't work (and obviously how to fix it though)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

It does not works in all cases because of security issue.

You can load any image in canvas by converting that image to base64 string and then bind to canvas.

Example:

```
<img src="www.example.com/name.png" alt="test" />
```

to

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,vnaXYZetc..." alt="test" />
```

then load it to in canvas.

Thank you.